# How to create folds around a cylinder

Tags: edit-mode, cloth-simulation

I am unable to proceed very far in this video for creating folds around a cylinder. The problem arises when one tries to **select Random in edit mode** which is not available in 3.1. How shall I proceed?

https://youtu.be/fINXU7uTpFE?t=49

Comment: Select Random is available in 3.1, go into the header menu > Select > Select Random

Comment: @moonboots: is that not in object mode? I tried it and didn’t see any random vertices highlighted…

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this is 3.1: https://zupimages.net/up/22/36/0frw.gif

Comment: @moonboots! Thanks. I was selecting all nodes before selecting random. Cheers